# JS Menu sliding (always jumps to top of page)

Tags: javascript, slide

I created some sliding menu and all works great without one small problem. When I slide the menu, I'm automatically transported to the top of page (the slide effect works good, but why I'm transported to the top of page when I try to open the menu, when I scrolling page, when I'm not of the top?)

Position of the menu is fixed, so I can slide it when I'm in the center of page, for example.
So in short: I want to slide my menu without automatically jumping to the top of page (when I do it).

Code of js:

```
    <script>
    jQuery('.arrowleft').click(function () {
      jQuery(".other_sidebar_background").css("display", "block");  
      jQuery(".other_sidebar").toggle("slide");
    });

    jQuery('.back_sidebar').click(function () {
      jQuery(".other_sidebar").toggle("slide");  
    });

</script>
```

My menu is showing when I click image in `.arrowleft` div (and hiding when I click image in `.back_sidebar` div). `.other_sidebar_background` and `.other_sidebar` it divs of my slide menu.

```
    .other_sidebar {
       z-index: 999999 !important;
       display: none;
       background: rgba(21,21,21,0.98);
       z-index: 9999;
       height: 100%;
       position: fixed;
       width: 270px;
       padding: 10px;
}

.other_sidebar_background {
       display: none;
       background: #2c2c2c;
}
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why, I might need to see what other elements are on the page, however, I'd try two things. One remove the height on the other_sidebar, I'm guessing that the height is equal to the height of the page, and therefore causing it to jump to the top of that element, which is the top of the page. If that doesn't work, try removing the fixed position and change it to a relative position, a specified distance from the top. I'm assuming other_sidebar is a child of the window so the fixed top isn't being effective at all.

Answer (score 3):

The divs (`back_sidebar` and `arrowleft`) were between `<a href="#"></a>` tags and the link "#" caused the problem.

I fixed it by changing the `<a href="#">` to `<a style="cursor: pointer;">` (I wanted a cursor link).